# Loading Remote values for Editor - Extjs

Tags: extjs, editor, grid

In a Extjs application, I want to load different values for a combobox editor of a column in editor grid panel. The values would typically come from a server call. How to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this example by Saki: http://examples.extjs.eu/?ex=combo